# What is the difference between "Getting Started" and "Get Started"

Tags: meaning, differences

I am writing a technical user manual (for software) and a bit confused about using "Getting Started" or "Get Started" term as a page title. Any suggestions?

Comment: Both are perfectly acceptable. _Getting started_ implies a description of the process, _Get started_ is a suggestion to the reader to do so, obviously to be followed by instructions.

Comment: They technically mean different things, but either one could be used as a title.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you, it is very clear now.